# django Q filter doesn't work.(Conversation matching query does not exist.)

Tags: django

I'm trying to make a chatting room. and here is my code.

```
def make_chatroom(request, user_one, user_two):
    user_one = user_models.User.objects.get_or_none(pk=user_one)
    user_two = user_models.User.objects.get_or_none(pk=user_two)
    if user_one is not None and user_two is not None:
        try:
            conversation = models.Conversation.objects.get(
                Q(participants=user_one) & Q(participants=user_two)
            )
        except models.Conversation.DoesNotExist:
            conversation = models.Conversation.objects.create()
            conversation.participants.add(user_one, user_two)
        return redirect(reverse("conversations:detail", kwargs={"pk": conversation.pk}))
```

but the Q filter doesn't work and this code go to except repeat.

when I erase try~except part, it occur error

> Conversation matching query does not exist.

user_one is exist, and user_two also exist. but conversation be made repeatedly. How can I fix it?

+add my models.py

```
class Conversation(core_models.TimeStampedModel):
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(
        "users.User", related_name="converstation", blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        usernames = []
        for user in self.participants.all():
            usernames.append(user.username)
        return ", ".join(usernames)

    def count_messages(self):
        return self.messages.count()

    count_messages.short_description = "메세지 수"

    def count_participants(self):
        return self.participants.count()

    count_participants.short_description = "참가자 수"


class Message(core_models.TimeStampedModel):
    message = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        "users.User", related_name="messages", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(
        "Conversation", related_name="messages", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} says: {self.message}"
```

Comment: `get` is expecting criteria that will match one record, usually something like `pk=1`. Try  using `filter` instead.

Comment: @urbanespaceman I exactly want to see just one record(i mean there is only one conversation between user_one & user_two). and sadly, when i trying to use filter, it just return <QuerySet []>

Comment: Show us your models

Comment: @iklinac I added my models.py on the post.

Comment: Sorry, been on holiday :) Yes, filter will return a queryset, which you could just take the first element of, or add `first()` to the original query to get just one item. Your error seems to imply you don't have any matching records though, rather than trying to fetch too many.